# Do sensor mode trip mines alert guards?

Tags: payday-2

One of the perks for Technician is the ability to turn trip mines into sensors that beep, instead of explode when tripped. Can guards see these, or hear when they are tripped?

Specific applications in mind include a "someone is coming up to the roof" detector for Framing Frame day 3, so the camera operator doesn't have to periodically check if there's a guard on the roof.

Comment: Incidentally, a year and some change later, sensor mines actually mark guards in stealth (and special units loud)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they will get a blue `?` mark when they hear the `beep`, but they won't react in any other way.

Comment: Which is a perfectly natural behavior for a person in charge of security, indisputably !  Haaa, Payday... ;D

Comment: @Anto I mean, a guard would probably think "What the hell is that beeping noise?" before they thought "There are robbers! Alarms! FBI! SWAT!"

Comment: A regular security agent would more probably piss himself when coming face-to-face with a trip mine nicely dropped on his path: bip or no bip, it's a rather trashy way to get rid of someone ;)